Import Kotlin Multiplatform dependency to a classic JVM gradle build
I have a gradle multi-project setup.
.
├── module-a (kotlin multiplatform)
├── module-b (standard jvm module)


The module-a has exclusively kotlin code. The build.gradle.kts script is:
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    macosArm64()

    applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()
    sourceSets {
        configureEach {
            languageSettings.progressiveMode = true
        }
        val kotlinCoroutinesVersion: String by project
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutinesVersion")
            }
        }
    }
}

My question is how can I "include" module-a to module-b as dependency?
In other words I would like to do something like (build.gradle.kts of module-b):
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":module-a"))
}

Is this possible?
Here it the real example:
https://github.com/smyrgeorge/komapper/commit/0e63dd67c89f61745de3cc3e69b308f9b0bc61d5
I changed the komapper-core module.
You can build it with:
./gradlew :komapper-core:build

And then I tried to build the komapper-dialect-h2
./gradlew :komapper-dialect-h2:build


check out this answer

Thanks for you reply. But it doesn't work in my case, I don't know why..

Yes, it should just work.
When you declare a dependency, Gradle makes use of variant-aware matching. For a project dependency, Gradle will look in the dependency project (here module-a) for configurations with attributes that match the attributes of the consuming dependency in the dependent project (here api in module-b) and accesses the artifacts and dependencies of that configuration.
Since module-a is a Kotlin multiplatform project with a JVM target, it will have a matching configuration and thus the module-b will be able to use module-a as a dependency.

Thanks for your reply. The thing is that does not work, the module-b cannot resolve the classes of module-a

You'll have to share some more details if you want more help. Like a link to the code repo. Seems like you may be overlooking something elsewhere in the project layout

Here is the commit:
https://github.com/smyrgeorge/komapper/commit/0e63dd67c89f61745de3cc3e69b308f9b0bc61d5

The structure of your multiplatform project is wrong. There is no main source set in a multiplatform project. Instead you have corresponding folders commonMain, jvmMain and macosArm64Main. See docs
